# Update vector with openmp C++

Tags: c++, memory, parallel-processing, openmp

I would like to update a shared vector in openmp, but the problem is that it is very slow. I would to know an efficient method to copy from host memory to device memory. Something like this:

```
vector<int> v1(750000);
#pragma omp parallel shared (v1){
    #pragma omp for schedule (auto)
        for (int i = 0; i<v.size();i++)
        v[i]=i;
        //int x = vi[i] is faster;

}
```

Times:
Execution time parallel with access v[i] = i: 6.84299 seconds

Execution time parallel with only read v[i]: 0.0119577 seconds

Execution time IO operations (other operations on DISK storage): 0.352074 seconds

Modify an array in shared memory is slower than doing disk access...

Comment: It is slower than disk access...

Comment: Your example is several orders of magnitude too small (and too trivial). Firstly, generating a thread pool and synchronizing the threads takes much more cycles than 100*x. Secondly parallelism can not speed up much memory transfers, because that is a shared resource. Parallel processing requires multiple calculating units to have something meaningful to process.

Comment: "very slow" is not a valid performance description. In any preformance related question you must provide a [mcve] that include the measurement methodology and specific measurement results.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer your question. 6.8 s is very slow for only `750000` elements. You need to show more code, state your compiler, what compiler options you used, what OS, and your hardware.